# Media queries: same height and different width

Tags: css, styles, media-queries

How to combine following media queries:

`@media (min-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1054px), (min-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px){}`

It works only for (min-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1054px), but for
(min-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px) is not working.

Comment: How wide is your screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Will work

```
@media all and (min-height: 768px) and (max-width: 1054px), (max-width: 1366px){}
```